# Are there any Sass code formatters?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Is there any code beautifier formatter for Sass (SCSS) code? I know how to format the output CSS code generated by SCSS compiler but how to give nice auto formatting to SCSS code itself?

I've tried some online CSS formatter but they don't work with SCSS code.

If i give this to them

```
.list5 {  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f1;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
ul li {
    margin: 0 0 5px 25px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    background: none !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 18px 3px 5px !important;
    width: 169px !important; }
 }
```

they give this output

```
.list5 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f1;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 25px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    background: none !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 18px 3px 5px !important;
    width: 169px !important;
}
```

which remove this part `ul li {}`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

## Online

Paste your `CSS`/`SCSS`/`LESS` into [dirtystylesheet.com](http://dirtystylesheet.com) and hit <kbd>Clean</kbd>

## Via Command Line

Via command line you can re-format `CSS`/`SCSS`/`Sass` using the `sass-convert` script:

```
$ sass-convert messy.scss clean.scss
```

or CSS to SCSS:

```
$ sass-convert messy.css clean.scss
```

or SCSS to Sass:

```
$ sass-convert messy.scss clean.sass
```

The `sass-convert` script is installed when you install Sass. It can convert any direction between: css, scss, and sass.

Learn more about `sass-convert`:

- Access the built-in help: `$ sass-convert --help`
- http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax
- http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/#executables

**Advanced user tip:** Because the `sass` syntax is much stricter (only allowing one `property: value` pair per line) you're less likely to run into an issue with messy code.

Comment: anything for windows user? Eclipse pluging ? :)

Comment: @xchg.ca i've created a basic Sublime Text 2 plugin that uses sass-convert https://github.com/badsyntax/SassBeautify

Comment: @xchg.ca - You should find sass-convert.bat in your Ruby install's bin folder.

Comment: Great! But is there any way to preserve new-lines?

Comment: Tried it but it messed up my code (problem with multi-line comments?). Luckily I made a backup.

Comment: How would this be called for each .scss in the folder? thanks!!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - `sass-convert folder_name/*.scss folder_name/*.scss`

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 will format it, just hit Ctrl-K-D or Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document

Comment: http://www.dirtystylesheet.com/

Answer (score 11):

http://hilite.me/ - supports Sass and Scss

JSFiddle will do the trick as well. Just hit the `TidyUp` button

Answer (score 2):

Pretty Diff will strip the "**$**" from your variables.

You can try: http://www.prettyprinter.de/

It's not perfect but at least  it indents an extra level for nested rules and from what I've seen keeps all the scss stuff untouched (.ie does not strip it out).

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code through [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify) and I got this output:

```
.list5 {
    border-bottom:1px solid #f2f2f1;
    padding:0 0px 20px 0px;
    margin:0 0px 20px 0px;
    ul li {
        background: none !important;
        font-size: 14px;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: 0px 0px 5px 25px !important;
        padding: 18px 3px 5px !important;
        width: 169px !important;
    }
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?  It looks strange for CSS.

Comment: Hummmm, beautification is imperfect for SCSS from Pretty Diff, but appears functional.  I am working on fixing what flaws are visible from this immediate example.

Comment: are you creator of Pretty Diff?

Answer (score 1):

If you use sublime text I can recommend SassBeautify to quickly format any sass/scss
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SassBeautify