# Auto Indenting Compass/SASS files

Tags: sass, compass-sass, indentation

Is there any simple way to auto-indent SASS/Compass files? I want to maintain the indentation inside the hierarchy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any Sass code formatter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799346/is-there-any-sass-code-formatter)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer depends on which editor you are using.
there are many editors who provide the auto-indenting feature,such as VIM, which is my
favorite.  It can auto-indent when you write.  or you can use `gg=G` to format entire file after you finish